# Optaplanner CVRPPDTW with different capacity types

Tags: optaplanner

we have a vehicle routing problem with some additional requirements (different capacities, time windows, pickup/delivery).
While looking for a tool to solve this we found OptaPlanner. But after reading the documentation (and some forum entries), we are still not sure whether the problem can be modeled with it.

What we need:

- customers order pickup and delivery

  - with different capacities (e.g. 2 x type A, 1 x type B, 1 x type C))
  - and with time windows (pickup after a certain time, delivery before a certain time).
- there are different vehicles with certain capacities (e.g. one vehicle has 8 places for type A, 5 places for type B, 2 places for type C, another one 10 places for type A, 2 places for type B, none for type C,...)
- the pickups and deliveries should now be distributed to the vehicles in such a way that capacities and time windows are of course maintained and

  - every pickup / delivery of a customer is carried out by the same vehicle (for all different capacity types)
  - pickups and / or deliveries of other customers can take place between the pickup / delivery of a customer (as long as the capacities are maintained)

Can this problem be mapped and solved with Optaplanner?

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Mixed pickup and deliveries are hard to do efficiently. Here's how OptaPlanner can do it efficiently: (warning: "here be dragons") https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment
Some of our customers/users have used it successfully. One day we'll clean it up, document it and add it to optaplanner-quickstarts and get rid of the boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you! We'll look at it and see if we can handle it.

Comment: Hello Geoffrey,
we tried to build this as a Maven project via pom.xml. But have problems with the resolution of the dependencies.
We switched to the newest version (7.46.0.Final) we found in the repository  
The dependency org.jfree.jcommon could not be found, so we commented it out for testing purposes.

Then the following error occurred

Could not find artifact org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:6.2.1 in nexus (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)  (org.ow2.asm is not mentioned directly in the pom file)

Do you have any help or advice to resolve the dependencies?

Comment: I just tried and quickly upgraded that repo, yet it still doesn't work any more. There's a domain corruption left, but I don't have the bandwidth to investigate without proper motivation (support ticket). It's a big pity that I used a SNAPSHOT dependency in 2017 so it is now broken. (snapshots are not reliable). That being said, it is fixable and it did work well, so if you can understand the ideas behind that code, it might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update.
We could now build and start it. Hopefully we can fix the errors at runtime ourselves.
Thank you so much for the help!